# Load table after function gets executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to hide the below table onLoad of page and display it as soon as the function `fnValidatefields()` executes fully. Please suggest some pointers.

```
<input type='button' name='button' value='Find' onclick="fnValidatefields()">
<table><tr><td></td><tr></table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most standard and convenient way would be to initially *hide* the table by *stylesheet definition* like

```
.yourTableClass {
    display: none;
}
```

and within your `fnValidatefields` function, you reset that value.

```
function fnValidatefields() {
    // ...
    $('.yourTableClass').show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add style `display: none;` to the table and change it after the function executes successfully.

```
<input type='button' name='button' value='Find' onclick="fnValidatefields()">
<table style="display: none;" id="table1"><tr><td></td><tr></table>

fnValidatefields() {
    //ur code...
    document.getElementById("table1").style.display = "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<input type='button' name='button' value='Find' onclick="fnValidatefields()">
<table style="display:none;" id="tbl"><tr><td></td><tr></table>
```

In Script file use like this:

```
function fnValidatefields()
{
   //code...

   $("#tbl").show();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hide your table at first with:

```
$('table.hideTable').hide();
```

And in your fnValidatefields() you can use

```
$('table.hideTable').show(); // Shows the table again
```

Comment: A) don't use inline style, but set classes B) use JS to hide the table, thus in case JS is disabled everything still works

Comment: @feeela Good points. That's what I'm doing when I write my own code.